# MIPS cross-compile package, libc6-dev-mips-cross, is missing libcrypt

Tags: apt, compiling, gcc

I am trying to cross-compile a program for the MIPS architecture that requires libcrypt.

It works on a machine that has the Ubuntu Focal release, and that make sense since I can find libcrypt in the libc6-dev-mips-cross package listing:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/libc6-dev-mips-cross/filelist

On my newer machine that has Jammy, the compile isn't working because it is missing libcrypt. I can see that it is missing in the package listing:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/libc6-dev-mips-cross/filelist

Why was libcrypt removed? Is there a way to get it on my Jammy machine through the package manager? If I have to cross-compile it myself, what's the best way to do that?

Comment: In case anyone comes across this: in an attempt to fix my issue, I cross-compiled openssl, but that actually provides libcrypto and not libcrypt. libcrypt comes from glibc. To avoid having to cross-compile glibc, I gave up on trying to compile the target application (Dropbear) with password authentication enabled, and just went with key authentication instead (no libcrypt needed).